# Using Windows API or WMI to determine if a process is displayed in the taskbar

Tags: python, windows, winapi, taskbar

So, I'm writing a dock/taskbar like application. What I want to do is pretty simple, display a list of running programs.

I've found lots of ways to enumerate all running processes, but after hours of google searching, I can't find a way to determine which of those should be displayed in a taskbar.

Take for example the Windows Task Manager. It has two tabs, one entitled Applicationss, and one entitled processes. Processes contains all of the system processes, whereas programs somehow gets a list of "applications" running on the computer. I want to be able to access the list of applications in my program, rather than the list of processes, so that in my pseudo-taksbar I'm not displaying things like taskhost.exe, winlogon.exe, etc.

Ideally I would be able to get the exact list of programs displayed in the taskbar. My program is in Python, and I have Windows API and WMI access, but if I have to write python wrappers for C functions I will do so.

As far as I can tell, the Windows Tasksbar API is more for doing things like adding menups or progress bars to existing icons, I couldn't find ways to access the information I'm looking for. Am IO mistaken?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it just uses the top-level visible windows.

Comment: @Luke No it doesn't. It's the top-level, visible, unowned Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules for which top level windows appear in the taskbar are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In summary:

> The Shell creates a button on the
>   taskbar whenever an application
>   creates a window that isn't owned. To
>   ensure that the window button is
>   placed on the taskbar, create an
>   unowned window with the WS_EX_ APPWINDOW extended style. To prevent the window button from
>   being placed on the taskbar, create
>   the unowned window with the WS_EX_ TOOLWINDOW extended style. As an alternative, you can create a hidden
>   window and make this hidden
>   window the owner of your visible
>   window.

For more discussion take a look at [Raymond Chen's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/08/5351207.aspx) on the matter.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful, and seems to be just what I was looking for. I'm having some difficulties getting a path to the executable file from the window handles, but that's a separate issue...